# Youtube data api v3 search all uploaded and posted videos by a specific channel

Tags: java, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm using Youtube data API version 3. Searching all videos inside a a specific channel using the java code provided.

In youtube.com I can see two kinds of videos inside a channel's Videos tab

- Posted Videos (uploaded by other channels)
- Uploaded Videos (uploaded by this channel)

When searching through the api, by setting a specific channelId, api returns only the videos which are uploaded by that channel.
Is there any way to get posted videos also?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Read the developer key from the properties file.
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        try {
            InputStream in = Search.class.getResourceAsStream("/" + PROPERTIES_FILENAME);
            properties.load(in);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("There was an error reading " + PROPERTIES_FILENAME + ": " + e.getCause()
                    + " : " + e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }

        try {
            // This object is used to make YouTube Data API requests. The last
            // argument is required, but since we don't need anything
            // initialized when the HttpRequest is initialized, we override
            // the interface and provide a no-op function.
            youtube = new YouTube.Builder(Auth.HTTP_TRANSPORT, Auth.JSON_FACTORY, new HttpRequestInitializer() {
                public void initialize(HttpRequest request) throws IOException {
                }
            }).setApplicationName("youtube-cmdline-search-sample").build();

            // Prompt the user to enter a query term.
            String queryTerm = getInputQuery();

            // Define the API request for retrieving search results.
            YouTube.Search.List search = youtube.search().list("id,snippet");

            // Set your developer key from the {{ Google Cloud Console }} for
            // non-authenticated requests. See:
            // {{ https://cloud.google.com/console }}
            String apiKey = properties.getProperty("youtube.apikey");
            search.setKey(apiKey);
            search.setQ(queryTerm);
            search.setChannelId("UCEgdi0XIXXZ-qJOFPf4JSKw");

            // Restrict the search results to only include videos. See:
            // https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#type
            search.setType("video");

            // To increase efficiency, only retrieve the fields that the
            // application uses.
            search.setFields("items(id/kind,id/videoId,snippet/title,snippet/thumbnails/default/url)");
            search.setMaxResults(NUMBER_OF_VIDEOS_RETURNED);

            // Call the API and print results.
            SearchListResponse searchResponse = search.execute();
            List<SearchResult> searchResultList = searchResponse.getItems();
            if (searchResultList != null) {
                prettyPrint(searchResultList.iterator(), queryTerm);
            }
        } catch (GoogleJsonResponseException e) {
            System.err.println("There was a service error: " + e.getDetails().getCode() + " : "
                    + e.getDetails().getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("There was an IO error: " + e.getCause() + " : " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using the [`Search: list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) specifying the channelId, you will got 248 results. It means that these results are the video uploaded by the user. But, this is not mean that he owns it.

For better explanation, I use this parameter.

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list?part=snippet&channelId=UCEgdi0XIXXZ-qJOFPf4JSKw&_h=1&

I use the `channelId` that you specify in your question. We will get the first result like this.

```
"snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2015-12-03T17:14:46.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCEgdi0XIXXZ-qJOFPf4JSKw",
    "title": "Kobe's Farewell Tour",
    "description": "Kobe Bryant announced that this season, his 20th, will be his last, and is saying goodbye to fans around the league.",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/FR0AqkteAYw/default.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/FR0AqkteAYw/mqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/FR0AqkteAYw/hqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "Sports",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
   }
  },
```

You will notice that the title of the first result is **"Kobe's Farewell Tour"**, by getting this video, I found out that this is a Playlist and if you check its content it compose of different video uploaded by different user.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FR0AqkteAYw&list=PL8fVUTBmJhHLB3FW_53W1P0mtmwRTCEK_

[image]
[image]

So these are the videos that you see in the channelId=UCEgdi0XIXXZ-qJOFPf4JSKw. So to get all the video use the [`PlaylistItems: list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) on all the playlist that you got in the search.list.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks, This won't work in my case because I'm setting the 'type' parameter value as 'video', you probably missed it in my code. I'm searching only for videos, not playlists, but your solution works in a sense.